# How do I restore a deleted file encryption key on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, certificate, public-key-encryption

I deleted my file encryption key from User Certificates in the Control Panel. I understand that Windows does not delete the private key and that User Certificates only deletes the key from the registry. How can I recover my deleted key?

Comment: "How can I recover my deleted key?" - If you did not specifically backup by exporting the certificate, then it cannot be restored, the key is permanently lost.  What you want is not possible.

Comment: Have a look at this article. https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/the-case-of-accidentally-deleted-user-certificates.aspx

Comment: The key has been deleted from my personal store using certmgr.msc. The private key remains on my hard drive while I do not have access to the public key. What I want to know is how to get hold of the public key.

Comment: Did you follow the directions in the article you linked? What happened?

Comment: I do not know what the CAComputerName or CAName must be on a standalone pc.

Comment: I don't use Windows, but why can't you simply create a new public key?  The private key is the bit that is important - and this should allow you to derive a new public key.  Alternatively, if you have used the public key elsewhere you should be able to retrieve it from there.  A public key is just that - public - so there is no reason to make it difficult to view.

Comment: You don't need to know the CAComputerName or CAName. From [Microsoft Certreq](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296456(v=ws.11).aspx): "If you don’t specify the CAComputerName or CAName in -config CAComputerName\CANamea dialog box appears and displays a list of all CAs that are available."

Comment: You have posted a bounty - could you tell us why `certreq` does not work for you to regenerate the public key, as described above. You should also post the output of `certreq -store`.

Comment: As has been asked a couple of times, the output of "certreq -store" would be very helpful here, because there seems to be some confusion about what you actually deleted.  
If you deleted the user file encryption certificate (the private user-level key) from you system via Cert Manager, you're stuck.  Yes, the file-level keys still exist, but they need the user cert to unlock them.  Without that cert, there is no access to the file key or the encrypted file's contents.  Do you have a backup (either of the certificate, or of the system with the cert installed)?

Comment: @Ruscal: The guy has disappeared after posting the bounty, so no point in making an effort.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962112.aspx)? Topic is pretty old but if you're still experiencing problem it might help.

**(edit)**

**Essence:**

Key are stored in "%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\"

User's master key is stored in "%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Protect"

Comment: Hi maaboo, please take the essential part here, keeping the link as reference, so the answer will be useful even if the link expires.